# robots.txt to disallow folder, but allow sub-folder

Tags: robots.txt

I'm fairly new to robots.txt but have the basics. My first problem is that I'd like to disallow all the translated pages, except in the help file.

So I have this:

```
Disallow: /de/
```

But I want, at the same time, to ALLOW one subfolder of the translations, namely:

```
Allow: /de/help/
```

How can I show this in robots.txt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to explicitly allow the subfolder you want crawled, while disallowing the rest of the folder. So something like:

```
User-agent: * 
Allow: /de/help/ 
Disallow: /de/
```

This will tell all search engines that you're allowing this one subfolder (and anything in it, including other subfolders - you're allowing a path, essentially) but otherwise disallowing everything else in this folder. Best to include the Allow directive above Disallow.

On the subject of robots.txt, more [info from Google here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/robots_txt).